# How to collect DISTINCT nodes which have DISTINCT property

Tags: neo4j

I have this query which returns all of the user's posts that have been commented on:

```
  MATCH (author:User {user_id: { user_id }})

  MATCH (post:Post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(author)
  WHERE post.createdAt < { before }

  MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)
  WHERE NOT author.user_id = commentAuthor.user_id

  WITH
    author,
    post,
    comment,
    commentAuthor,
    count(DISTINCT commentAuthor) as participantsCount,
    count(comment) as commentsCount
  ORDER BY comment.createdAt DESC

  RETURN collect(DISTINCT post {
    .*,
    author,
    commentAuthor,
    commentCreatedAt: comment.createdAt,
    participantsCount,
    commentsCount
  })[0..{ LIMIT }] as posts
```

This works great besides that if the same user decides to troll and comments on the same post multiple times, that post gets returned multiple times for that same user. This makes for some spammy notifications:

```
user1 commented on your post "what's your favorite book?"
user2 commented on your post "what's your favorite movie?"
user3 commented your post "what's your favorite show?"
user3 commented your post "what's your favorite show?"
user3 commented your post "what's your favorite show?"
```

^ all of user3's comments for that post get returned

If possible, I would only like to collect the distinct posts with distinct comment author, ordered by most recent.

```
user1 commented on your post "what's your favorite book?"
user2 commented on your post "what's your favorite movie?"
user3 commented your post "what's your favorite show?"
```

^ only returns user3's most recent comment

I'm basically trying to do something along the lines of:

```
collect (DISTINCT post { DISTINCT commentAuthor ... ])
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your query would always return 1 for participantsCount and commentsCount for each row. Are you seeing that too, or are you getting expected results?

Comment: Good catch... I don't display that in the UI immediately so I missed it, but yes it is incorrectly returning 1 - 1 for those counts.

Comment: Working on an alternate query. Is `comment.createdAt` a numeric timestamp?

Comment: Would you also want commenters collected per post? Even if we fix the commenter issue so a commenter only occurs once per post, you'll have as many rows for a single post as there are commenters on that post.

Comment: Yes comment.createdAt is 'timestamp()' of when it was created. Yes, I am currently collecting the commenters per post as 'commentAuthor'. I want the user notified of the most recent comment by a unique user for each post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `commentCreatedAt` map property is likely the culprit here, as you'll have different timestamps per comment. You'll likely need to get the latest comment, so if you use `max(comment.createdAt)` (if it's a numeric timestamp) that should allow those rows to collapse.

Let's also correct your counts. Keep in mind that your aggregations only have meaning with respect to the non-aggregation columns, which act as grouping keys. Since you have each `comment` and `commentAuthor` on a row in your WITH, your aggregations will result in 1 for `participantsCount` and `commentsCount` (since they're aggregating with respect to each single comment on each line, not all comments).

You'll need some way to get the aggregation on your comments either on its own (by removing `comment` from the line) or by collecting or aggregating the comments.

Here's one approach, where we'll aggregate first on the comment info we need per commentAuthor, then we'll collect the commentAuthor info per post, which will also let us aggregate the total number of comments and participants per post.

Then, to match the output from the query in your description, we'll unwind the authors and collect the posts along with each commentAuthor in its own entry.

```
MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)

  WITH
    post,
    commentAuthor,
    // since we don't have a comment per line, we can aggregate across all comments per post/commentAuthor
    max(comment.createdAt) as lastReplyAt,
    count(comment) as commentsPerCommenter
  ORDER BY lastReplyAt DESC

  WITH post, 
    // able to sum across all comments/commenters per post since we're collecting commentAuthor
    sum(commentsPerCommenter) as commentCount, 
    collect(commentAuthor {.*, lastReplyAt, 
      commentCount:commentsPerCommenter}) as commentAuthors

  WITH post,
    commentCount,
    size(commentAuthors) as participantsCount,
    commentAuthors

UNWIND commentAuthors as author

RETURN collect(post {
    .*,
    author,
    commentCount,
    participantsCount
  })[0..5] as posts
```

However, if you want one post per row, aggregating the commentAuthor info within each post, this query might work better for you:

```
MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)

  WITH
    post,
    commentAuthor,
    max(comment.createdAt) as lastReplyAt,
    count(comment) as commentsPerCommenter
  ORDER BY lastReplyAt DESC

  WITH post, 
    sum(commentsPerCommenter) as commentCount, 
    collect(commentAuthor {.*, lastReplyAt, 
      commentCount:commentsPerCommenter}) as commentAuthors

RETURN post {.*,
    commentCount,
    participantsCount:size(commentAuthors),
    commentAuthors}
LIMIT 5
```

Though this last query returns 5 posts in any case, since each post will have its own row instead of being duplicated per commentAuthor.